# PHP foreach loop, every amount of steps create new wrapper outside loop

Tags: php, foreach

I need some advice on this one. If I have a PHP foreach loop:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <?php foreach ($item as $element): ?>
    <!-- some HTML of $element -->
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

and after every 5th `$item` I want to create a new `.wrapper` with the next 5 items in the foreach. And redo this step until all are through. 
The output should be like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- some HTML of $element 1 -->
  <!-- some HTML of $element 2 -->
  <!-- to $element 5 -->
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- some HTML of $element 6 --> 
  <!-- to $element 10 -->
</div>
```

Do I need to run another `foreach` outside to make this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Actually no you have to do the opossite,aka to echo the wrapper in for loop every 5 $items

Comment: @Akis and how exactly to I ask for `every 5 items`.

Comment: you can add a counter and compute the modulo 5 ;) exactly as neil proposed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$i = 0; 
<?php 
    foreach ($item as $element) { 
        if($i%5==0) echo "<div class=\"wrapper\">";
?>

        <!-- some HTML of $element -->

<?php
        if($i%5==4) echo "</div>";
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think that this code will not do the job. It will wrap the first element in the div, then the fifth, etc... All the other elements will be outside the div. Did you test it?

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php $counter = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach ($item as $element): $counter++; ?>
        <!-- some HTML of $element -->
        <?php if ($counter % 5 === 0 && $counter !== count($item)): ?>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$i = 0;
<?php foreach($item as $element) : ?>
        <?php if($i == 0) : $i=5; ?>
              <div class="wrapper">
        <?php endif; ?>

           <!-- some HTML of $element -->
        <?php $i -= 1; if($i == 0) : ?>
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```